# "Traversing" un-nested divs with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse an HTML structure like this, with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (the actual code is slightly messier and contains links and images in between, but those don't seem to be an issue):

```
<div class="members">

    <div class="membergroup">Admin</div>

        <div class="membername">Member 1</div>
        <div class="membername">Member 2</div>
        <div class="membername">Member 3</div>


    <div class="membergroup">Moderator</div>

        <div class="membername">Member 4</div>
        <div class="membername">Member 5</div>


    <div class="membergroup">Member</div>

        <div class="membername">Member 6</div>
        <div class="membername">Member 7</div>

</div>
```

I'm having trouble finding some reasonable way to list all members in a particular group (I can't be sure how many members there are in each group). Some sort of loop might be appropriate, but I can't figure out how to print say 1st member of the 3rd group (Member 6 in this example).

There is a manual, but I've been unable to find a solution: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

The way the divs are structured, none of the members are actually nested inside the "membergroup" divs, but rather directly underneath them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

    require_once 'scripts/lib/simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html('test_reference.html'); // The example shown above

    // We know the total amount of members.
    // However, we don't know who and how many belong to a particular group in advance.
    $membercount = 7;


    $e = $html->find('div.members', 0)->find('div.membergroup', 0);

    if ($e->plaintext === "Admin") {
        echo "We are inside the 'Admin' div now!<br />";

        echo "Member is called: ";

        // ... But we have to go back to the parent,
        // because 'membername' isn't inside 'membergroup' :-(
        echo $e->parent()->find('div.membername', 0)->plaintext;

        echo "<br /><br />";
    }

    // Same thing, but to the third group ('Member') now instead of 'Admin'
    $e = $html->find('div.members', 0)->find('div.membergroup', 2);

    if ($e->plaintext === "Member") {
        echo "We are inside the 'Member' div now!<br />";

        echo "Member is called: ";

        // Wrong! We want the first (0th) member of the 'Member' group.
        echo $e->parent()->find('div.membername', 0)->plaintext;

        echo "<br /><br />";
    }
?>
```

The output will be:

> We are inside the 'Admin' div now!
>      Member is called: Member 1
>
> We are inside the 'Member' div now!
>      Member is called: Member 1 // This is wrong, should be 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have found the `membergroup` for which you are looking, use the following line of code in a loop until it returns another `membergroup` or reaches the last element:

```
$e = $e->next_sibling();
```

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - API Reference](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

> *element* `$e->next_sibling()`
>
> Returns the next sibling of element, or null if not found.